# Efficient algorithm to find number of elements less than a query

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have two unsorted arrays `a` and `b`. For every element `a[i]` I need to find the number of elements `b[j]` such that `b[j] < a[i]`. In addition `b` may contain duplicates which should not be counted. Both arrays may be very large.

I tried (for a single query `x`)

```
public static void main(String arg[]) {
    int x = 5;
    int b[] = {2, 4, 3, 4, 11, 13, 17};
    Arrays.sort(b);
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < b.length; ++i) {
        if(b[i] < x) {
            if(i == 0)
                ++count;
            else {
                // this check avoids counting duplicates
                if(b[i - 1] != b[i])
                    ++count;
            }
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count);
}
```

My problem is that this doesn't perform well enough when querying all elements of `a` iteratively. What can I do to speed this up?

Comment: @BeyelerStudios  
thanks for the comment  I asked here one part of my code I have two array a & b of big size 10^5 and for each element 'i' for array 'a'. I have to chk in array b the count of element less then & element greater then i .note array contains duplicate elemnt also

Comment: You totally changed the question. *"find the no of element less then x"* (interpreted as "count number of elements") and *"find the index of an element lower than x"* is entirely different questions. To find the index of *any* element lower than x, just find the index of the lowest value. That index is the answer to all x values, except when x is below lowest value, in which case answer is "not found".

Comment: @Andreas ohhh it was changed because of editing by some other person.i hv done rollback now.

Comment: I edited your question to summarise what I could extract from the comment section. Can you check if this accurately describes your problem?

Comment: @BeyelerStudios: where in vks's code do you see _two_ arrays? There seems to be just one, named _a_ in the description and `b` in the code.

Answer (score 5):

EDIT: given the later comments, some updates which I just put right in the beginning; leaving my first text at the bottom.

So, the core aspects here are:

1. You came here with some problem X, but further asking told us that you actually had some problem Y to solve. That is something that **you** should try to avoid: when coming here (or when working on problems on your own!) ... then you should be able to clearly describe the problem you have or intend to solve. I am not fingerpointing here; just expressing that you  should work **hard** to ensure that you understand what your *real* problem is.
2. This is also visible from the fact that *you* are asking *us* what to do about duplicate numbers in your data. Err, sir: it is **your** problem. We do not know why you want to count those numbers; we do not know where your data is coming from; and how the final solution should deal with duplicate entries. In that sense, I am just rephrasing the first paragraph: **you** have to clarify your requirements. We can't help with that part at **all**. And you see: you only mentioned duplicates in the **second** array. What about those in the first one?!

OK, so about your problem. Thing is: actually, that is just "work". There is no magic there. As you have **two** very large arrays, working on unsorted data is an absolute no-go.

So, you start by sorting both arrays.

Then you iterate over the first array and while doing that, you also look into the second array:

```
int indexWithinB = 0;
int counterForCurrentA = 0; // and actually ALL values from a before
for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
  int currentA = a[i];     
  while (b[indexWithinB] < currentA) {
    if (indexWithinB > 0) { // check required to avoid using 0-1
      if (b[indexWithinB-1] != b[indexWithinB] { // avoid counting duplicates!
        counterForCurrentA++;
      }
    }
    indexWithinB++;
  }
  // while loop ended, this means: b[indexWithinB] == or > currentA
  // this also means: counterForCurrentA ... should have the correct value
}
```

The above is obviously pseudo code. It is meant to keep you going; and it might very well be, that there are subtle errors in there. For example, as Andreas pointed out: the above needs to be enhanced to check for b.length, too. But that is left as exercise to the reader.

That is what I meant with "just work": you simply have to sit down, write testcases and refine my draft algorithm until it does the job for you. If you find it too hard to program this initially, then take a piece of paper, put down two arrays with numbers ... and do that counting manually.

Final hint: I suggest to write plenty of unit tests to test your algorithm (such stuff is **perfect** for unit tests); and make sure that you have all your corner cases in such tests. You want to be 100% sure that your algorithm is correct before going for your 10^5 element arrays!

And here, as promised, the original answer:

Simply spoken: iterating and counting is the most efficient way to solve this problem. So in your above case, leaving out the sorting might lead to quicker overall execution time.

The logic there is really simple: in order to know the count of numbers smaller than x ... you have to look at **all** of them. Thus you have to iterate the complete array (when that array is not sorted).

Thus, given your initial statement, there is no other thing than: iterate and count.

Of course, if you have to this counting multiple times ... it might be worth sorting that data initially. Because then you can use *[binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)*, and getting that count you are looking for works without iterating all data.

And: what makes you think that iterating an array with 10^5 elements is a problem? In other words: are you just worried about a potential performance problem, or do you have a **real** performance problem? You see, at some point you probably had to **create** and **fill** that array. That for sure took more time (and resources) than a simple for-loop to count entries. And honestly: unless we are talking some small embedded device ... 10^5 elements ... that is *close to nothing*, even when using slightly outdated hardware.

Finally: when you are worried about **runtime**, the simple answer is: slice your input data, and use 2,4, 8, ... threads to count each slice in parallel! But as said: before writing that code, I would do some **profiling** be sure that you really have to spent precious development time on this. Don't solve hypothetical performance problems; focus on those that **really** matter to you or your users!

Comment: thanks for the answer but there is performance issue ,I asked here one part of my code I have two array a & b of big size 10^5 and for each element 'i' for array a i have to chk in array b the count of element less then & greater then i .

Comment: i am thinking can we use Self Balancing BST here that wud be o(nlon) ?

Comment: Then I would sort *both* arrays. And compute counts in one shot.

Comment: *Clarification:* "In one shot" means parallel iteration of the two sorted arrays.

Comment: @Andreas thks man but how it cud be done in one shot ?i have to check for each elemnt of a in b then, for each elemnt of a i have to traverse b right?

Comment: @RajuSingh No, after they are both sorted, you iterate them in parallel. Why would you start the search over from the beginning of `b` when progressing to the next `a` value? You know that the `b` to locate is at or after where you already are in `b` (after doing the search for the previous `a` value).

Comment: @Andreas like this ??  for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
      
      while(i<b.length){
       if(a[i]<x){
        count++
       }else{
        break;
       }
       System.out.println(count);
      }
     }

Comment: @RajuSingh No. Two iterator variables, one for `a` and one for `b`. Iterate through `a`, and for each value forward the `b` iterator until value (or higher) is found.

Comment: @Andreas I got it thanks for explanation .i have one more qstn how to handle count for duplicate since here, simultaneously i will calculate count of no greater tnn 'x 'by doing (size of a-count of element  less then 'x'). but this will contain count of duplicate element in higher side .

Comment: @vks I updated my answer to fit your latest requirements.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for "taking" over; to value that work I just upvoted some other answer from your side ;-) I significantly enhanced my answer; and hope that it resolves the "new" question.

Comment: A few comment to updated answer: 1) Typo: `a.lenth`. 2) Goal is "number of elements less than", so don't reset counter between `a` values. 3) You don't check `indexWithinB` against `b.length`, so you're going to get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Ok, you did cover this with the "pseudo code" statement. --- *Side comment:* If you wanted to count duplicates, then `indexWithinB` *is* the count of `b` values less than the `a` value. ;-)

Comment: @Andreas Thank you very much. Updated my answer. But its late here, so who knows what else hides in there ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Comapring every item in the array with x will take you O(n) time. Sorting the array will take O(n log n), and then you can use binary search, which is O(log n), and you get a total of O(n log n). So the most efficient way is also the trivial one - just loop thru the array and compare every item with x.

```
public static void main(String arg[] ){
    int b[]={2, 4, 3, 4, 11, 13, 17};
    int x=5;
     int count=0;
     for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++){
         if(b[i]<x){          
             count++;
         }
     }
     System.out.println(count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose you to consider the following approach, but it works only if the `b` array has non-negative numbers. The algorithm works even if input arrays (both `a` and `b`) are not sorted.

**Pseudo-code**

1. Get the `max` element of array `b`.
2. Create a new array `c` of size `max + 1` and put `1` in the position `c[b[i]]`.
3. Create a new array `d` of size `max + 1` and populate it as follow:

   `d[0]=0;`
   `d[i]=d[i-1] + c[i];`
4. Create a new array `e` of size `n` and populate it as follow:

   `if(a[i] > max) then e[i] = last(d)`
   `otherwise e[i]=d[a[i]-1];`

`e` array represents the solution: it contains in i-th position the counter of numbers of the `b` array lower then the i-th element of array `a`.
This example should be more explicative than the pseudo-code:

```
a = [5, 1, 4, 8, 17, 12, 22]
b = [2, 4, 3, 4, 11, 13, 17]
c = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
d = [0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6]
e = [3, 0, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6]
```

**Complexity**

```
Steps 1, 2 and 4 are O(n).
Step 3 is O(max(b))
```

if the input array `b` contains only "short" numbers (max(b) is in the same order of `n` size) the algorithm perform in `O(n)`.
The algorithm could be optimized creating an array of size `max-min+1` and consider counter `0` for all the elements of `a` array lower than `min(b)`.

**A simple java implementation:**

```
int a[] = {5, 1, 4, 8, 17, 12, 22};
int b[] = {2, 4, 3, 4, 11, 13, 17};
int max = Arrays.stream(b).max().getAsInt();
int c[] = new int[max+1];
int d[] = new int[max+1];
int e[] = new int[a.length];
for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++){
    c[b[i]]=1;
}
for(int i=1;i<c.length;i++){
    d[i] = d[i-1] + c[i];
}
for (int i = 0; i<a.length;i++){
    e[i]=(a[i]>max)?d[d.length-1]:d[a[i]-1];
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(c));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(d));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(e));
```

Answer (score 0):

For larger sorted set we need to use Divide-And-Conquer principle to fasten our search.Here is my solution which has O(logn) Time complexity and O(n) space complexity.

```
public static void main(String arg[]) {
    int x = 5;
    int b[] = {2, 4, 3, 4, 11, 13, 17};
    int high = b.length - 1;
    int low = 0;

    while (high >= low) {
      int mid = (high + low) / 2;
        if (b[mid] < x)
          low = mid + 1;
        else
          high = mid - 1;
    }
  System.out.println(low);
```

}

Answer (score -1):

This should be a possible solution. The"expensive" task is the sorting of the lists. The bost list must  be sorted before the for loop. Make sure you use a fast mechanism to execute the sorting. As explaned a sort on an array /array list is a very expension operation especially if there are many values you have to sort.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // int x = 5;
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int b[] = { 2, 4, 3, 4, 11, 13, 17 };
    List<Integer> listA = new LinkedList<>();
    for (int i : a) {
        listA.add(i);
    }
    List<Integer> listB = new LinkedList<>();
    for (int i : b) {
        listB.add(i);
    }
    Collections.sort(listA);
    Collections.sort(listB);
    int smallerValues = 0;
    int lastValue = 0;
    Iterator<Integer> iterator = listB.iterator();
    int nextValue = iterator.next();
    for (Integer x : listA) {
        while (nextValue < x && iterator.hasNext()) {
            lastValue = nextValue;
            nextValue = iterator.next();
            if (nextValue > lastValue) {
                smallerValues++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(x + " - " + smallerValues);
    }
}
```

Comment: As described in the answer. The sorting is expensive but the compare itself has a complexity of O(n). Because each item of both lists will only be touched once.